# Calculate reducing total from sections of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array `A`

```
A = [{id:1,month:"January",amount:2000},{id:2,month:"February",amount:3300},{id:3,month:"March",amount:2500},{id:4,month:"May",amount:3000},{id:n,month:"June",amount:5000}]
```

I would like to get the sum of the values from `Id:1 to Id:3`

```
[{id:1,month:"January",amount:2000},{id:2,month:"February",amount:3300},{id:3,month:"March",amount:2500}]
```

Which cumulatively will be `7800` and hold that in a Variable `_temp_var_1`. Then get the sum of the values form `Id:4 to Id:N` and hold that in another variable `_temp_var_2`.

`N` represents the last id

I am using the following code to calculate the reducing total

```
A.reduce((result, a) => {let _amount = a.amount;
  return result + _principal_amount;
  }, 0);
```

Comment: its very simple, just loop the array and some in your variables based on functionality you want. just search how to loop in javascript or jquery.

Comment: A `for` loop could work here, I also suggest checking out the MDN doc for [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Comment: @Ajay2707  I have an idea of calculating the reducing total. The problem i am having is breaking down the two sections.

Answer (score 3):

try this.

```js
var A = [{id:1,month:"January",amount:2000},{id:2,month:"February",amount:3300},{id:3,month:"March",amount:2500},{id:4,month:"May",amount:3000},{id:'n',month:"June",amount:5000}];

var sumOsSpecificIds = (arr, ids) =>  arr.reduce((sumVal, elem) => { if(ids.indexOf(elem.id) != -1) sumVal += elem.amount; return sumVal;},0);

console.log('ids: 1 - 3', sumOsSpecificIds(A, [1, 2, 3]));
console.log('ids: 4 - n', sumOsSpecificIds(A, [4, 'n']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily iterate through all elements and check if they are within the allowed ids, and add up the sum.

```js
let A = [ {id:1,month:"January",amount:2000},
          {id:2,month:"February",amount:3300},
          {id:3,month:"March",amount:2500},
          {id:4,month:"May",amount:3000},
          {id:5,month:"June",amount:5000}];

function findSum(fromId, toId) {
  let sum = 0;

  A.forEach(e => { 
    if(e.id>=fromId && e.id<=toId) 
      sum += e.amount 
  });
  return sum;
}

console.log(findSum(1,3));
```

Comment: This works, but what happens in a situation where the Ids are not in a logical order

Comment: @SteveGaita my answer does not care in which order the data is laid out. It will check each element and see if its id is within the specified range